# Invoke jar file via bat and get the output to same console

Tags: java, command-line, batch-file, jar

I have test.jar which just contain a single class and it has a main method. That just prints out some string to std out. I need to run this jar using .bat file. So I used

```
@echo off 
start java -jar E:\FYP\jartest\out\artifacts\jartest_jar\jartest.jar %1
```

in my script. 
When I run the bat file the output does not print to the same console. Instead it is opened in another window.

( What I understand is I should put some 'echo variable' where the output of the java program should be assigned to 'variable'.  Or There might be some other ways ).

What should I do?

Thank You !

Comment: Why do you use "echo off"? And why do you use "start"? The start is the one starting another window. But this is a windows related question and not restricted to java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `start` is what is causing the new window to pop up and the output is going there.  Change your bat file to say this instead:

```
@echo off
java -jar E:\FYP\jartest\out\artifacts\jartest_jar\jartest.jar %1
```

You can also remove the `@echo off` if you want.  If you remove that line, the windows shell will print out the lines it's executing in your bat file.  I'd personally leave `@echo off` there except when you're trying to debug the bat file.